# Extra data in downloaded files (PHP)

Tags: php

I am trying to set up a PHP page to be able to download some log files.

I have tried searching (very hard) for a solution, but I don't really know PHP or HTML, so I have tried many snippets from many sources.

```
<?php
$dir =  "/home/pi/fluidLogs";

$phpfiles = glob("$dir/log*.txt");
foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
  echo '<a href=?file=' . $phpfile . '>' . basename($phpfile) . '</a>';
  echo ' - Last mod: ' . date("Ymd-H:i:s", filemtime($phpfile));
  echo ' - Size: ' . filesize($phpfile);
  echo '</a><br>';
}

if(isset($_GET['file'])){
  header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
  header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($_GET['file']) . "\"");
  readfile($_GET['file']);
}
?>
```

For example one file should contain,

> This is a fake log file. 
>   OK?

with a new line before OK?, but this (and all the downloaded files (via Chrome)) have the same extra data on the first line, 
[image]
Sorry about the image. The contents were not being displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user is requesting for a file, i.e. clicked on your anchor link, do not echo the list of files, which are then echoed on top of the file.

```
<?php    
    if(isset($_GET['file'])){
          header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
          header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
          header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($_GET['file']) . "\"");
          readfile($_GET['file']);
        }
    else{
        $dir =  "/home/pi/fluidLogs";
        $phpfiles = glob("$dir/log*.txt");
        foreach ($phpfiles as $phpfile) {
          echo '<a href=?file=' . $phpfile . '>' . basename($phpfile) . '</a>';
          echo ' - Last mod: ' . date("Ymd-H:i:s", filemtime($phpfile));
          echo ' - Size: ' . filesize($phpfile);
          echo '<br>';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Wow, what a fast response (and it works)! Thank you ;) So, if the user is not requesting a file, the list is built and the links are shown on the webpage?

Comment: I guess I don't need the second </a>, so I could change "echo ' - Size: ' . filesize($phpfile);
          echo '</a><br>';" to "    echo ' - Size: ' . filesize($phpfile) . '<br>';
"

Comment: Yes, I missed that extra anchor tag. And yes, the user will see the list when he access the page without file GET parameter ?file=